# Vector function that represents the curve of intersection of the two surfaces

Tags: calculus

When they ask you to solve: the cone $z= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$   and the plane $z=1+y$

You can just say $ z^2= x^2 + y^2 => (1+y)^2= x^2 + y ^2$
This gives $x^2= 1-2y => y= 1/2(x^2-1)$

And then just say $x=t$ which gives $y= 1/2t^2 -1/2$ and $z= 1/2t^2 + 1/2$

So why can't you apply the same method with:
the hyperboloid $z= x^2-y^2$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$
and just say $y=\pm\sqrt {1-x^2}$
and say x=t, which gives you $y=\pm\sqrt {1-t^2}$ and $z=-1$

Why do you have to use sin $t$ and $\cos t$ here, for $x$ and $y$ respectively?

Comment: paraboloid $ x^2+y^2 = z  ? $

Comment: should have been x^2-y^2=z, sorry

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing it your way. You just have an arithmetic error going from $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $z=x^2-y^2$ to $z=-1$. Plug in the value of $y$ and try again.